# substract from date tuple

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have an index consisting of Date tuples.

```
2005-02-04 00:00:00        31.81        31.81        31.81        31.81   
2005-02-07 00:00:00       31.885       31.885       31.885       31.885   
2005-02-08 00:00:00      31.5326      31.5326      31.5326      31.5326
```

I would like to add a row at the top of the index, and I use the
following way:

```
df.ix[ (df.index.min()) - dt.timedelta(minutes=5), :]    =
     ([ dict[n] for n in df.columns.values.tolist()])
```

dict contains some values, but it's irrelevant here I think. However,
I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

The type of the Index is: df.index.dtype gives type Object as opposed
to Datetime as it should I suppose. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I ve found it, you simply need to take the first element off the tuple, and it returns a 'TimeStamp' object:

```
df.index.min()[0] - dt.timedelta(minutes=5)
```

works